# Scaling a view to fit screen rotation/EMULATING onScale() method

Tags: java, android, canvas, scaling

I am building sketch app and I would like to support screen rotations. But on rotation i would like to resize my view like in gallery (so it fits one coordinate). I was using canvas, matrix, screenanimator and lots of other stuff to scale it to landscape or portrait mode, but sadly I can't achieve it.

So question is how could i scale my drawed canvas to fit landscape and portait mode?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I actually want to achieve what I get with pinch to zoom. I want to zoom out my view. setScaleX doesnt give me result i need, so I need to somehow emulate onScale() method from ScaleGestureListener. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any other efficient method but this works for me -

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ABCDActivity.class));
    }
}
```

So everytime there is a orientation change, you can load a new activity. Alternatively, you can create a fragment with canvas and stuff and then instead of loading the whole activity, just load the fragment with canvas drawed to fit landscape mode when there is a orientation change.